# Jquery Date Picker arrow key should be prevented

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to force the user to only use the drop down and calendar to
select a date in the DatetimePicker control.

I do NOT want them to select the control, then use the up and down
arrow keys to change the date.

How can I prevent them using the arrow keys?

Any help much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $(".datepicker").datepicker({
               changeMonth: true,
               changeYear: true
           });
       });
       $(function () {
           $(".datepickerApplyyear").datepicker({
               changeMonth: true,
               changeYear: true,
               yearRange: '0+100'
           });
       });
   </script>
```

FYR:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#datepic").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      duration: 'fast',
      stepMonths: 0
    });​
```

This will disable the user to select using next and previous buttons.

Comment: this disables the user to select, but in my test it displays it... See: http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/FRvpa/1/

Comment: @Neysor the buttons are visible but you cannot navigate through the buttons. I've tried with hideIfNoPrevNext but that doesnot work

Comment: yes but this isn't a real solution! It isn't good for a user to see an arrow that does not work. This seems to be a bug although it isn't. You should also use css and hide the arrows! (see e.g. my post) This is the reason why i dislike this "working" solution :)

Comment: @Neysor yes i could see your post. If the `WebDeveloper` combines both the answer or else yours it would be perfect for him i guess.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a config called `hideIfNoPrevNext`, but this seems not to work.
I would use the following CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-prev {
    display:none;
}
.ui-datepicker-next {
    display:none;
}
```

See also following: http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/5tX8q/3/

​